# Compressing aged rollover files using log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Do you know a way (preferrable requiring only configuration) to tell log4j-2 to only compress some of its rollout files (those reaching a given age)?

The context of the problem is an application logger using both time and size triggering policies. It's required that only the older logs shall be compressed (and discarded when reaching another configurable age limit).

I would prefer to avoid any external tool to handle the framework-managed logs.

I'm also opened to solutions using different java logging frameworks (better if they are commons-logging compatible).

Thanks!